# Quickly select entire page in Okular

Tags: pdf, clipboard, copy, paste

Okular provides a nice way to copy a selection from a pdf onto the clipboard as an image. Most of the time I'm interested in copying the entire page, but I haven't found a way to make a selection other left-click+drag. Is there a way to quickly copy the entire page of a pdf as an image, either in Okular or some other viewer?

*Just to clarify, I'm interested in solving this with the fewest number of actions possible. Bonus points for accuracy (i.e. getting exactly the full page onto the clipboard), but that's not the main issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Fast method

1. Open the PDF document in the default Document Viewer application (okular) and scroll down to the page you want to copy.
2. Select *View* -> *Fullscreen*.
3. Create a screenshot of the page on the screen using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>PrtScn</kbd>. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>PrtScn</kbd> will take only the particular window which is currently active.

#### Slow method

The slow method gives you more options for customizing the copied image.

1. Install GIMP image editor from the Ubuntu Software Center.
2. Right-click any pdf file and select *Open With* -> *GIMP Image Editor*.
3. GIMP will open and show an **Import from PDF** window. Click the page or pages from the PDF document that you want to import in order to select them.
4. Click the *Import* button.

[image: Import from PDF]

4. From the Layers/Channels/Paths Dock select the *Layers* tab and then select a PDF page to export as an image by clicking it. If you want to edit the image before exporting it, you can do this now or else continue on to the next step.
5. Select *File* -> *Export As*...
6. In the bottom right corner of the **Export Image** window select the format of the exported image from the dropdown  menu. The format of the exported image can be PDF or any one of the many image formats that GIMP supports.
7. Click the *Export* button.

Comment: Hi Karel, this definitely does the job, but I'm looking for a much quicker solution.